# Using bash - How can I put substring inside a parameter from a file

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file called result which looks like this:

```
{"id":10722,"type":"BRANCH","value":"refs/heads/master","branch":{"id":"refs/heads/master","displayId":"master","latestChangeset":"d53ae5dbaa5e4b2f7b007e94ee91ae2de7e600b6","isDefault":true}}
```

Using bash, How can I put the substring after **"id:"** (in this example 10722) inside a parameter?  (*e.g*  param=10722)

I need to keep in mind that this file is changing all the time so counting characters is not something I would want to use.

Comment: Looks like JSON data, better to use `jq`

Comment: agree...problem is I can't rely on the fact that jq will be installed because it is a remote server that I have no control over it.

Comment: You can try, but it leads to [...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/26428)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like JSON data. Better to use `jq` like this:

```
jq '.id' file.json
10722
```

If `jq` is unavailable then use `gnu grep`:

```
grep -oP '"id":\K\d+' file.json
10722
```

Comment: `\K` directive resets all matched information and `\d+` matches 1 or more digits.